# C++ says gcd is not a member of std

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am using visual studio 2017 and I have run across a problem. When trying to use `std::gcd` it gives me an error `error C2039: 'gcd': is not a member of 'std'`

Here's my code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::gcd(10, 5);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Did you enable `-std=c++11` with your compiler flags?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ im not sure what that means. But shouldn't i be using c++17?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It should be `-std=c++17` according to the [reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The command-line option in MSVS is `/std:c++17`, not the same as GCC or Clang.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`std::gcd`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) was added in C++17. To use it in Visual Studio you need to specify the language standard. You can do that two ways, use the `/std:c++17` command-line option or in the Project Properties dialog: C/C++ -> Language -> C++ Language Standard.

Comment: Thanks! I would assume that VS 2017 would use C++17 by default. Why isn't this the case?

Comment: @JoyalMathew Here's [documentation for the `/std` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2017). It does default to C++14, you would have to ask them why.

Comment: @JoyalMathew: VS2017 is from May 2017, C++17 was approved in December 2017.

Comment: VS2017 works with C++17 and `std::gcd`. I have tested it in VS2017 15.9.6. There is no problem.

Comment: @user5280911 The problem is that VS2017 defaults to C++14 unless changed via a compiler option. Using `std::gcd` without also specifying the C++17 language standard will produce a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and got the same error with VS2017 15.8.9 after having set the language standard to C++17. When I checked my project settings again, the language setting I made had reverted back to the default. After having set it a second time, it worked.

This seems to happen often when I start a new project and change to C++17 directly.